# How to detect url attribute action was complete and connected between users in twilio?

Tags: twilio

I set url attribute for number and client verb for some scripts. I had some delay to execute that scripts so I want to detect when connect between users after the scripts. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that Twilio can tell your application the status of a call.

- Set the **Voice Request URL** to get updates during the call (and respond with additional TwiML).
- Set the **Status Callback URL** to get the results at the end of the call.

This page will explain this in detail: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request